# How to show invocation module arguments using official stdout_callback plugins?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've been using the `human_log.py` callback plugin (https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log or https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180) for some time now. When a task runs, it shows information useful for debugging:

```
TASK [server : Install nginx] ************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.2]
{ '_ansible_no_log': False,
  '_ansible_parsed': True,
  'cache_update_time': 1548736000,
  'cache_updated': True,
  'changed': False,
  'invocation': { 'module_args': { 'allow_unauthenticated': False,
                                   'autoclean': False,
                                   'autoremove': False,
                                   'cache_valid_time': 0,
                                   'deb': None,
                                   'default_release': None,
                                   'dpkg_options': 'force-confdef,force-confold',
                                   'force': False,
                                   'force_apt_get': False,
                                   'install_recommends': None,
                                   'name': 'nginx-extras',
                                   'only_upgrade': False,
                                   'package': ['nginx-extras'],
                                   'purge': False,
                                   'state': 'present',
                                   'update-cache': True,
                                   'update_cache': True,
                                   'upgrade': None}}}
```

I recently became aware of the existence of the Ansible `stdout_callback` option. For example, in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = debug  # or json, or yaml, etc.
# Alternative method: stdout_callback can be set as an environmental variable instead.
# For example: ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook tasks.yml
```

With `stdout_callback = debug` set, the output is:

```
TASK [server : Install nginx] ****************
ok: [192.168.1.2] => {
    "cache_update_time": 1548738000,
    "cache_updated": true,
    "changed": false
}
```

It's nice to have an official way for showing more information in the output, but the official plugins have one glaring omission: `invocation` and `module_args` are missing. The output does not show the arguments that the module was called with.

Is it possible to show the module arguments in the output without using third-party plugins (such as `human_log.py`)?

(Reference: the full list of official `stdout_callback` plugins is here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list. Note: the plugins only show their effect when `ansible-playbook` is run using the verbose flag [`-v`])

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the location to request such a function.
You should head over to the official pages and make a request over there.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues

Interesting plugin tho!

Answer (score 0):

Executing `ansible-playbook` with `-vvv` verbosity shows `invocation` parameters even with default stdout callback.

Comment: Yes, but it also shows a ton of other information such as every SSH connection made, and every shell command run.